# Can we use beamforming to make sure that the signal will not make interference together in Full duplex?if yes,why?

Tags: digital-communications

To avoid signals will make interference to each other in full duplex,there are two methods to solve this problem.

Time-division duplexing and Frequency-division duplexing,they just use different frequency or time slot to transmit and receive the signal,so these two method can make sure that  signal won't have interference.

However, i want to know if there are two MIMO devices(two devices  are both with multiple received antennas and multiple transmitted antennas) in full duplex.

Can we use SVD to design the beamforming of these two devices to avoid their transmitted signal won't be the interference to each other in the same frequency and time ?

For example:A want to transmit signal to B ,and B want to transmit signal to A,so there will be two channel $H_{AB}$ and $H_{BA}$.So when i do SVD,and get the beamforming direction,$v_{ab}$ and $v_{ba}$,how do i prove that these beamforming can help the signal to avoid becomeing the interference of other signal?

Here is my thinking ,but i don't know right or wrong,the  $H_{AB}$ and $H_{BA}$ are random,so it is nearly impossible to let $H_{AB}$ be equal to $H_{BA}$,so it is impossible to let $v_{ab}$ be equal to  $v_{ba}$ or $v_{ab}=-v_{ba}$ ,so indeed  these beamforming can help the signal to avoid becomeing the interference of other signal.Is my thinking right?

Comment: *However, i want to know if there are two MIMO devices(two devices are both with multiple received antennas and multiple transmitted antennas) in full duplex* $$\,$$yes, there are.$$\,$$ *Can we use SVD to design the beamforming of these two devices to avoid their transmitted signal won't be the interference to each other in the same frequency and time?* $$\,$$yes, you can, with varying degrees of additional effort.$$\,$$ **Was this really your original question or did you mean to ask something else?**

Comment: yes they are my original question,but i want to ask more

Comment: hm, do you want to achieve the self-cancellation using SVD *alone*? Because then, you'd need at least as many receive antennas *on each side* as there are transmit antennas *in total*.

Comment: yes! i will also achieve the self-cancellation using SVD alone